# CM stand for cervical mucus VS CM standS for cervical mucus

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

What is the correct way?

1. CM stand for cervical mucus (without s in the end of stand)
2. CM standS for cervical mucus (with s in the end of stand)

Comment: I hope you are a med student or something. TMI, otherwise.

Comment: TMI stands for Too Much Information (with the s!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When we cite acronyms, or words or even phrases, we treat the whole citation as singular. A citation is when we mention the acronyms or words but we aren't actually using them in a normal way in the sentence. We could, for example, put the word(s) or acronym in 'quotes', or in *italics*:

- *AIDS* is short for *Acquired Immune Deficiency Syndrome*
- 'Not very tall' usually means 'short'.
- *UN* stands for *United Nations*.
- "Buenas noches" is "good evening" in Spanish.
- *CM* stands for *cervical mucus*.

In the examples above we see the third person singular verb forms *is, means, stands* instead of the plural forms *are, mean* and *stand*.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: You just beat me to it, and in more detail. +1 for making my answer obsolete! :) (You even used the same example, UN!)

Comment: @oerkelens That makes a change! It's normally *you* who beats *me* to it :D

Comment: This is one of those things that makes English difficult... a blatant disregard for any sort of order or logic.  First the nouns give you the rule that you add an "s" to make plurals, then the verbs turn around and do the opposite. A tree *grows* but *trees* grow... go figure.

Answer (score 5):

Sentence 2 is the better because CM is singular.